# Api version greater than 14 does not launch emulator in android studio

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio

I am developing an application using android studio, I tried to run application but emulator did not lauch. I also tried to directly run emulator but still it is not launching, it only shows message as: `"D:\Android set up\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\tools\emulator.exe" -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd AVDNew`

I had created 3-4 new AVD but not working. I also created one AVD with api versiom 10 then it run, I did not get why API version higher than 14 did not launch emualator.  Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: try running the emulator command from dos. DOS will print if there is any error

Comment: @Paritosh  Yes after launching it from command line it gives me error as: Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

Comment: I think you are having Intel System Image. For this to work, go to extras in SDK Manager and select Intel emulator accelerator. Install it.

Comment: Due to intel system images I am getting this issue. After creating new AVD with ARM processor solves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check your sdk version may be it is 14 or less
Go to the sdk manager 
and download latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Open `SDK Manager` -> select `API level` you want for emulator -> check desired `System Image` is Installed

If not, install `System Image` (requires Internet Connection). You are ready.

Note : Prefer ARM EABI System Image because some motherboards does not support HAXM .